# Ruby/RoR development: locally or server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Our company has started development of own systems "in-house". We already got couple of developers, who will be responsible for writing code in Ruby/RoR.

We are currently discussing about infrastructure and I would like to ask: should we develop everything on local machines, then put it to test server and later to production, or develop everything on development/test server, then publish it for testing and later to production?

Just an update to the description above: under "local machines" I meant developers' desktops and this test/development server is a machine in our office.

Comment: I see a lot of development questions that aren't necessarily programming questions. Is this the right place for it or is there another overflow better suited to it?

Comment: If you're writing web apps, it's best to develop locally, regardless of language. Saving to a server and using a remote application is slower than doing things locally - plus having the server in your normal development flow forces you to be connected to the web (or forces you to be in an office, depending on your firewall).

Comment: Yes to having remote test and live web servers. You may want branch servers as well, one per feature branch. Unless your testing load is particularly large, all your non-live stuff can go on one physical/virtual server. Make sure you all know a good version control system, and that everyone is committed to using it.

Comment: I don't think it is the right place for this question...

Comment: A better place is probably http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid question, and as such there's a trade-off to consider.

Generally; work locally. Web app development has a natural flow that leads developers to be saving and refreshing browsers many times an hour. All the time you save on network latency will actually add up, and be less frustrating for the developers.

There are downsides to working locally however, you'll need to make sure that your set-up is EXACTLY as it will be on the  testing/production servers. That means everything down to your kernel version, apache version, ruby/rails version. DNS is easy, but again must mimic the live situation perfectly in order for AJAX calls etc to work seamlessly.

Even if you ensure all of the above, you will likely have to make a few minor changes when you move the app to a live server, there just always seems to be something in my experience.

Also, running on a live server isn't SO painful for a developer. Saving a source file from a text editor/IDE via FTP should take less than a second even over the internet, and refreshing a remote browser session will give your UI designers a better feel for the real user experience and flow. If you use SVN rather than FTP much the same applies.

Security isn't much of a concern, lock down FTP and SSH to the office IP, but have a backdoor available if a developer needs to edit a source from somewhere else, so they can temporarily open the firewall to their own IP.

I have developed PHP and Rails apps on a remote test server, on an in-office server and on a local machine. After many years doing each, I can say that as a developer, I don't mind any so much.

Comment: I think you overplay the need to have your dev env match your production env, assuming you're not running something super out dated on either end. Obviously you want to be deploying to the same ruby+rails+gems versions but bundler,rvm,etc handles that pretty well. It might help to have the same OS but I develop on OSX and deploy to Debian with no troubles. If you're hardcoding domains in your ajax calls you're probably doing it wrong unless you really are calling out to different services.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, my suggestion is that you need to 1st do all developing work on your local server. After testing, you need to send to client to make it live.

I'm working as a web developer on *Ruby on Rails* @ **andolasoft.com**, we are following the same procedure. Hope you got the idea.

Thanks